# Drupal: how to *always* show a specific node on top of my View?

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I'm using Views in Drupal.

I would like to show a specific node always on top of my View regardless of other sort criterias.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. in Views - add sort type: "Node: Sticky" - descending order.
2. In node adding/editing click on "Sticky at top of lists" in Publishing options.

Answer (score 0):

Nikit is right. Sticky is built into the default content types for just this reason.  But you have to add it to your sort type.

Or, you could add your own CCK type and sort by that, if you're already using Sticky for something else.

Or, if you're sorting by post date, for example, override the post date to be sometime far in the past or future, depending on how you're sorting, but that's a hack.

Answer (score 0):

Well, make sure that sort criteria is at the top of your sort criterias list. ;)

Comment: it's 5 years that I don't use Drupal but thanks for the answer :)